# RxJava - using delaySubscription with withLatestFrom together

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

It is difficult to explain my problem, that's why I will try to explain with a more simple example. (I will also include my case in parentheses to make clear why I need to solve this problem)

```
    val interval =
        Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

    val delayedRandomNumber =
        Observable.fromCallable {
            val randomNumber = Random().nextInt()
            Log.d("LogTag", "random number = $randomNumber")
            randomNumber
        }.delay(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)

    interval
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .filter { it != 0L }
        .delaySubscription<Int>(delayedRandomNumber)
        .withLatestFrom(delayedRandomNumber, BiFunction<Long, Int, String> { second, randomNumber ->
            "$randomNumber mod $second = ${randomNumber%second}"
        })
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe {
            Log.d("LogTag", it)
        }
```

**interval** - it is obvious that this emits value every second (in my case it is user input emited from EditText)

**delayedRandomNumber** - this generates a random number and emits it after 5 seconds. I need to generate only once but for now I do not know how (in my case it is json tree of cities from server)

**delaySubscription** - I am using this operator to wait for the random number. If I do not use this I will not get value for second values 1,2,3 (in my case I need to start with the first letter because it is tree based data - I have such constraint)

**withLatestFrom** - I am using this operator to avoid generating the random number every time (in my case I do not want to get data from server every time when input changed)

So I need to use **delaySubscription** and **withLatestFrom** together. But it is making problem by generating random number twice (in my case loading data twice)

When I run this code, log looks like this:

```
random number = -1870536123
random number = -1834197628
-1870536123 mod 1 = 0
-1870536123 mod 2 = -1
-1870536123 mod 3 = 0
-1870536123 mod 4 = -3
-1870536123 mod 5 = -3
-1870536123 mod 6 = -3
```

As you can see the random number is generating twice.

Is there other way to solve this problem? If yes how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `delayedRandomNumber` is [cold observable](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html) or unicast. Each subscription will have its own producer (in your case random number generation inside Observable.fromCallable is the producer).

To avoid this issue, you could multicast `delayedRandomNumber` by using [share](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#share--) operator.

```
    val delayedRandomNumber =
        Observable.fromCallable {
            val randomNumber = Random().nextInt()
            Log.d("LogTag", "random number = $randomNumber")
            randomNumber
        }.delay(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
         .share()
```

Output

```
random number = -942235082
result=-942235082
-942235082 mod 1 = 0
result=-942235082
-942235082 mod 2 = 0
result=-942235082
-942235082 mod 3 = -2
```

Please read [blog by Dan Lew](https://blog.danlew.net/2018/09/25/connectable-observables-so-hot-right-now/) too as I found it helpful when having issue with multicasted observable.